# calling view controller string from imagePickerController delegate method

Tags: iphone, delegates

the problem I'm having right now is

I'm calling this method: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

from vc1

I have a string1 from vc1 but it cannot be called inside that method

because that image delegate method is called from a different class.

When I NSLog(@"%@", string1); it only shows null

I want to retrive string1 from inside the image delegate method.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks much.

here's the source:

From ViewController

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

NSLog(@"%@", requestString);

NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

for (int i=0; i< [components count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"components %@", [components objectAtIndex:i]);
}

if([components count] <= 1) {
    return YES;
}

if ([(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"toapp"]) {

    NSLog(@"toapp %@", [components objectAtIndex:0]);
    // 1번째 문자열이 toApp인 경우

    if([(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"showphoto"]) {

        NSLog(@"showphoto %@", [components objectAtIndex:1]);
        // 2번째 문자열이 relationButton인 경우

        NSLog(@" objectAtIndex:2 %@", [components objectAtIndex:2]); // param2

        pictureName = [components objectAtIndex:2];

        //call photo library
        picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

}

I declared:

```
NSString *string1;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    viewcontroller *v = [[viewcontroller alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"string1 %@", v.string1);
}
```

exc_bad_access

From Console:
string1 (null)

I want to see string Helloworld from the console.
I cannot call a string pictureName from inside the imagePickerController delegate method.

Comment: have you tried self.string1? And if you debug, and open the self part, can you see the string Helloworld?

Comment: i think its because the delegate method is called from different class becaue it says exec bad access on string1 i need to know how to call string1 from diff class

Comment: how do I delete my post? I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog(@"string1 %@", *string1);` incorrect
`NSLog(@"string1 %@", string1);` correct

Format `%@` needs a `NSString*` instead of a `NSString`. `string1` is a `NSString*`.

---

**Update** : I noticed that you replace the part with:

```
viewcontroller *v = [[viewcontroller alloc]init];
NSLog(@"string1 %@", v.string1);
```

That's not correct. You initialize `string1` in `viewDidLoad`, but you use the `string1` of `v` which has never been loaded. And I don't think you should create a new vc object. If you need a constant string, just go ahead to use `@"Helloworld"`. If you want the string of the current object, you should use `self.string1` instead of create a new object. Be aware that there's no `static variable` in Objective-C.

Let's try this:

1. make sure you have write `NSString * string1;` in the .h file of the vc;
2. replace `string1 = @"Helloworld";` 
   with `string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",@"Helloworld"];`
3. replace the body the delegate method with `NSLog(@"string1 %@",self.string1);`

Comment: Absolutely correct. But just to let you know, the question has changed already. I'm just posting this so nobody gives you a -1 because your answer doesn't make sense with the revised question.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. The question changed while I was typing my previous answer. How embarrassing...

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is only called after (as the name suggests) its view was loaded. That happens when you present the viewController somehow. E.g. pushing it to a UINavigationController, add it to a UITabBarController or present it modally.

If you want to use the string1 before your viewController loads its view you should put `string1 = @"Helloworld";` into `init` or `initWithNibName:bundle:` or whatever you use to initialize your second viewController

---

Btw, you forgot a `[super viewDidLoad]` at the beginning of your viewDidLoad method.
And your class names are wrong, they should start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

just had to do [retain string1];

don't need viewcontroller *v = [[viewcontroller alloc]init];

thanks.